# Close Hamburger Menu on Nav Item Click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to close the nav menu after clicking on a nav item. Obviously, the nav menu will close when it is directed to a new page. Unfortunately, the nav menu will stay open, covering the whole page, when it is directed to an anchor of the same page. I can not say what is or isn't relevant so I have included the bulk of the code. In my previous attempts to fix this issue, I expected that menu would disappear upon a nav item, leading to anchor, click, but I have not yet succeeded.

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const border = document.querySelector(".border");
const contactimage = document.querySelector(".contact-image");
const contactBubble = document.querySelector(".contact-bubble");

hamburger.addEventListener("click", mobileMenu);

function mobileMenu() {
  border.classList.toggle("active");
  contactimage.classList.toggle("active");
  contactBubble.classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
.right-section {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.right-section ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

.right-section ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: var(--color-dark);
  font-size: 18px;
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
}

.bar {
  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: var(--color-dark);
}

.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-item {
  margin-left: 3rem;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: var(--color-dark);
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: var(--color-secondary-dark);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  ul {
    display: flex;
  }
  .border {
    position: fixed;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0rem;
    background-color: var(--color-light);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.3s;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 27px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  }
  .nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 35vh;
  }
  .border.active {
    left: 0;
  }
  .nav-item {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
  .nav-link {
    color: var(--color-secondary-dark);
  }
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
  }
}

.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
}

.hamburger.active .bar:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="right-section">
  <div class="border">
    <ul class="nav-menu" id="nav-menu" onclick="menuOnClick()">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="/home.html" class="nav-link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#reviews" class="nav-link">Reviews</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="/faq.html" class="nav-link">FAQ</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="/contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="hamburger" id="hamburger" onclick="menuOnClick()">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First, i don`t see declaration ofmenuOnClick function, second: it would be cool to see implementation of this code on platform like codesandbox

Comment: menuOnClick was part of an older trial that I forgot to remove. I kept the onclick in case I would need to use it again.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to close the menu upon clicking a nav item, just use the same approach as to toggle the menu with the hamburger. But, instead of using querySelector, use the **querySelectorAll()** method.

(I used .nav-link instead of .nav-item since that is the hyperlink they're clicking.)

```
document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link").addEventListener("click", mobileMenu);
```